# Bootstrap '.row' class with 'display: flex' causing 'text-align: center' not to work on 'p' tags

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am using [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) and I have a `div` with a `class` of `row` and inside that I have a `p` tag.

I added an `ID` to the `row` `div` and applied `text-align: center;` but the paragraph doesn't center align.

Yet, in [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) [Inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/), if I disable `display: flex` it will align.

Why is this?

```
#example {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```
<div class="row" id="example">
    <p>Example.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: share the code ... but my guess, is that you have nothing to align, the content to center already fit the p

Comment: I don't think a code sample was necessary, but I've added it to avoid the down vote.

Comment: it's necessary, because *you* are facing the issue with *your* code, this is not a generic issue, we need to see what is happening with *your* code ... and what you shared is still not enough

Comment: Respectfully, that's incorrect. Here's an example showing it is universal / generic: https://codepen.io/s3w47m88/pen/PeVjeQ

Comment: ah, this not generic but you simply need to understand how flex works and how text-align work ;) and my first comment was correct ... you have nothing to center as the text already fit the element. And saying `flex doesn't support text-align:center` is totally wrong

Comment: Try adding `width:100%` to p and see what happen

Comment: Maybe 'flex doesn't support' isn't the right language. But conceptually it's true that elements which have display: flex ignore text-align: center in favor of justify content center. Which is all I'm trying to say with that. Either way, I'm just hoping if I've complied with the requests of whoever down voted this that they would remove that since my question is universal and valid. :) Please and thank you!

Comment: Sorry but again this is totally wrong `it's true that elements which have display: flex ignore text-align: center in favor of justify content center.` .. text-align:center is valid and is never replaced by justify content ... text-align center text and justify content center flex items. Check this fiddle to understand more : http://jsfiddle.net/bpxf4tq0/6/ ... You are simply confusing about things and making wrong conlusion, all you need is to understand what is happening

Comment: Another example to better see : http://jsfiddle.net/bpxf4tq0/7/

Comment: Can anyone explain why I'm getting down votes? I don't understand what about my question is deserving of that and I'm willing to revise it to avoid them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171486/discussion-between-spencer-hill-and-temani-afif).

Comment: no one will reply to you here, as no one will get notified when you write here ... consider the meta website if you have any trouble and if you want to aks for such things https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written,  the `<p>` element is inside the `row`. Hence, it takes the full width of the row, `use` `text-center` to align text in center.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="text-center">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis sed nobis ratione natus exercitationem dolores suscipit dolore ab voluptatum expedita quo facilis laboriosam, soluta molestias nemo, possimus excepturi nihil odio! Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas eaque quae id, nam harum assumenda libero molestias aperiam corrupti consequatur, est doloribus vel corporis, ad consequuntur iure tenetur eum commodi!

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*If `text-center` does not work, use one of these methods*

Since `<p>` is a block level element, you can align it in the center of its parent using `mx-auto`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="mx-auto w-50">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis sed nobis ratione natus exercitationem dolores suscipit dolore ab voluptatum expedita quo facilis laboriosam, soluta molestias nemo, possimus excepturi nihil odio! Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas eaque quae id, nam harum assumenda libero molestias aperiam corrupti consequatur, est doloribus vel corporis, ad consequuntur iure tenetur eum commodi!

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Bootstrap row is `flex`, use `justify-content-center` to align all the content of the row in its center.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <p class=" w-50">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis sed nobis ratione natus exercitationem dolores suscipit dolore ab voluptatum expedita quo facilis laboriosam, soluta molestias nemo, possimus excepturi nihil odio! Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas eaque quae id, nam harum assumenda libero molestias aperiam corrupti consequatur, est doloribus vel corporis, ad consequuntur iure tenetur eum commodi!

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `justify-content: center;` for display: flex items

Comment: Thank you. Why is that required and why does text-align not work? Is this a broken feature of CSS / HTML or is this just something that came with the introduction of flex?

Answer (score 1):

The row is only used for columns...

> "Rows are wrappers for columns... Content should be placed within
>   columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."

You should use...

```
<div class="row" id="example">
  <div class="col">
    <p class="text-center">Example.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```